# Removing index.php in Codeigniter 3 apache2 server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, url

I am working on Code Igniter in Kali Linux, I have configured .htaccess file as mentioned in Documentation and configured file correctly but its not working without index.php

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

I have also enabled rewrite mode and restarted apache. Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: did you remoce "index.php" in config.php of $config['index_page']?

Comment: like $config['index_page'] = "";

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan Yes i did, but still the same problem!

Comment: below answer surely help you. if not check other codes

Answer (score 1):

in config.php

```
 $config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

create .htaccess file with the following at your project's loctation
(for eg: /var/www/html/yourproject create .htaccess inside 'yourproject' folder )

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

add the below to your virtual host configuration file

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/yourproject">
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            Allow from all
</Directorey>
```

then restart apache

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps to remove `index.php` from url

1)Remove "index.php" from config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

2) Your .htaccess file should be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

3)Some cases you also have to change this in config file

```
//find the below code
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO"
//replace with the below code
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

Comment: Yes i did but still facing the same problem!

Comment: Codeigniter 3 and up versions not have AUTO

Comment: Have you added `.htaccess` file at root directory?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```